# How to get the version of the RPM from inside the %pre script?

Tags: redhat, rpm

How to get the version of the RPM from inside the `%pre` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just `%{version}`? That macro would be expanded as needed in your `%pre` script.

Comment: Turns out it is. Can you please show me where it's written? I've spent hours reading the documentation without finding it.

Comment: Hrm... that I'm unsure of off the top of my head, sorry! I am pretty sure that all of the headers like "name" "version" "release" etc are available the same way as pseudo-macros.